# How to add a UIButton on top of UITabBar inside a UITableView

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, constraints

Does anybody know how i can create a UIButton (with constraints height: 35, leading: 0, trailing: 0 and bottom space to UITabBar: 0) inside a UITableView that has a bottom spacing of zero to the UITabBar implemented in the UITableViewController?

What i tried so far:

```
    let btn = UIButton()
    btn.setTitle("Test Button text", for: .normal)
    btn.tintColor = UIColor.white
    btn.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
    self.view.addSubview(btn)
    btn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    btn.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    btn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 0):

Subclass Uitabbar and assign that your tabbar. And then add your button code inside the class. Dont forget to uncheck cliptobound property of tabbar.

Comment: Could you be so kind and show me how to do this? I am still a beginner in swift.